# Carrierwave store original file after creating the version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have ImageUploader class and i want to save my original image with original size of the image after saving the particular version. Help me to solve this

Uploader

```
class ImageUploader < IconBase
 process :resize_to_fill => [490,68]

 version :normal do
  process resize_to_fill: [245,34]
  def full_filename(for_file = model.logo.file)
    "avatar1.png"
  end
 end

 def filename
   "avatar.png"
 end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Your original size is not saved, because you have `process :resize_to_fill => [490,68]` in your uploader. To keep original size, you can put this into another version, so your main image will stay unproccessed, like this:

```
version :large do
  process :resize_to_fill => [490,68]
end
```

Then you'll have:

```
uploader.url        # original image
uploader.large.url  # [490,68] version
uploader.normal.url # [245,34] version
```